# Populating DataTable column with JSON file but DataTable is empty

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, datatables

```
$.ajax({
  'url': 'http://localhost:8080/Retail-war/webresources/products/allProducts',
  'method': 'GET',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')},
}).done( function(data) {
  $('#existing-product').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
      { "targets": -1, "data": null, "defaultContent": "<button>View More Details!</button>"}
    ],
    "aaData": data,
    "columns": [
      { "data": "products.productId"},
      { "data": "products.originalPrice"},
      { "data": "products.currentPrice"},
    ]        
  })
```

This is my format of my JSON file and I would like to populate the DataTable with the 3 columns in products but nothing is showing up in the DataTable and no error is thrown too. How can I populate each columns with the columns in the JSON file under the **products** object?

```
  {
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": 1,
                "originalPrice": 60,
                "currentPrice": 50
            },
            {
                "productId": 2,
                "originalPrice": 80,
                "currentPrice": 70
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Just curious: What version of DataTables are you using? `"aaData": data` looks like pre-1.10. I would expect to see `"data": data` for version 1.10 onwards.

Comment: @andrewjames I am currently using the latest version. But is there any difference between how "aaData" and "data" does things in DataTable?

Comment: _Is there any difference...?_ No - it should not make a difference - backwards compatibility. But if you have the opportunity to use the new syntax, it's probably a good idea to do so.

Comment: Can you check your JSON?  What is posted in the question is not valid - extra commas may be causing issues.  For example: `"currentPrice": 50,` is not valid.

Comment: @andrewjames My apologies, the JSON actually have other columns as well and I didn't remove the "," from the sample I gave in the question. But the JSON is in the right format.

Comment: OK - no problem! Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing your data like this...

```
// does not work
"data": data,
"columns": [
  { "data": "products.productId"},
  { "data": "products.originalPrice"},
  { "data": "products.currentPrice"}
]
```

Change the initializer to this:

```
// works
"data": data.products,
"columns": [
  { "data": "productId"},
  { "data": "originalPrice"},
  { "data": "currentPrice"}
]
```

DataTable needs the iterable object you will be using to be outside of the columns definitions (where the iteration happens).

These changes work for me (in my stripped-down version of your example).

**UPDATE**:

As requested, here are some more details to explain the situation:

If you try to use `"data": data,`, then you are providing a JSON object which has this structure:

```
{"products": [an array of objects]}
```

This is used by the `columns` definitions to iterate over your JSON. But there is nothing to iterate over - there is only the one item - the array.

However, if you first drill down one level in your structure by using `"data": data.products`, you are passing the following JSON to your the `columns` definitions:

```
[{row 1 data}, {row 2 data}, ... {row n data}]
```

This can be iterated by DataTables, to populate each row in its table.

You can still drill down into each object being iterated, if there are nested objects.  In your case there aren't any nested objects - but imagine if your data looked like this (a totally artifical example, by the way):

```
{
    "products": [{
        "productId": 1,
        "originalPrice": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "amount": 60
        },
        "currentPrice": 50
    }, {
        "productId": 2,
        "originalPrice": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "amount": 80
        },
        "currentPrice": 70
    }]
}
```

In this case, we can access the data like this:

```
"data": data2.products,
      "columns": [
        { "data" : "productId" },
        { "data" : "originalPrice.amount" },
        { "data" : "currentPrice" }
      ]
```

Here we see the use of the dot notation to drill down into the `originalPrice` object, to grab the number we want to display: `originalPrice.amount`.

Comment: Hello thank you for the help. But can I know why does "products.something" not work in this case? Does that mean by default DataTable wouldn't write within the nested JSON if I just use "data" : data?

Comment: @JinWei - I added some notes and examples - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

By default DataTables expects the array to be called `data`. You can change it using the [dataSrc](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html) property, but only if you are using the built-in DataTables Ajax option, which to be honest is recommended anyway. Define your DataTable like this:

```js
$('#existing-product').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Retail-war/webresources/products/allProducts",
        dataSrc: "products",
        headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')},
    }
});
```

Alternatively rename your array on the server before you echo it back to "data"

Comment: Hi I have tried to use the dataSrc as well but it doesn't seem to populate any data into the DataTable columns too.